# How to change the boolean 'true' in for example 'left'

Tags: java, boolean

What is the correct code to change the standard boolean 'true' to for exemple 'left' or 'well done' or ...
So instead of giving 'true' when an expression is true, it has to give 'left' for exemple.
Thanks.

Comment: you cant assign any other value to boolean except true and false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `boolean` value can only be set to `true` or `false`. However, you can use that boolean value to determine other variables' values.

You can use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Java) `(expr) ? (value if true) : (value if false)`, which operates on boolean expressions:

```
boolean b = ...// true or false
String s = b ? "Well Done" : "Incorrect";
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a text value in boolean. But you can do something like this to return desired text if boolean is true:

```
boolean b; // set it to true or false
String str = b ? "well done" : "not really";
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

What I believe you want is a way of returning something depending on a boolean value.

Let's say you have a method:

```
public void tellUserResult(boolean result){
    if(result) {
        System.out.println("Nice play!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Too bad!");
    }
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand the logic.

Comment: I understand this, but here you make a new method, which is good, but I was more in need of a quick, simple version like the ones above. But thank you